Authentication fail. MongoDB
I'm making a mongodb database but I'm have a problem with authentication error but I don't know which part I did wrong. Hoping you can help me take a look through the authentication see if I'm making any mistake. Thank you for your help
This is my index.js
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

console.log(`MONGO_USER: ${process.env.MONGO_USER}`);
console.log(`MONGO_PASSWORD: ${process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD}`);

const uri = `mongodb://${process.env.MONGO_USER}:${process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD}@mongo:27017/myDatabase`;
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

async function run() {
  try {
    console.log(`Connecting to MongoDB at ${uri}`);
    await client.connect();
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Failed to connect to MongoDB", err);
  } finally {
    await client.close();
    console.log("Connection to MongoDB closed");
  }
}

run().catch(console.dir);


This is my secret yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mongo-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  mongo-user: bXlVc2Vy
  mongo-password: bXlQYXNzd29yZA==

This is my client yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo-client
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo-client
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo-client
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongo-client
        image: bentran2003/mongo-client:latest
        command: ["node", "/usr/src/app/index.js"]
        env:
        - name: MONGO_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongo-secret
              key: mongo-user
        - name: MONGO_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongo-secret
              key: mongo-password
        volumeMounts:
        - name: app-config-volume
          mountPath: /usr/src/app/index.js
          subPath: index.js
      volumes:
      - name: app-config-volume
        configMap:
          name: app-config
          items:
          - key: index.js
            path: index.js

I've try changing the the name or matching but doesn't seems to work.
kubectl get pods
NAME                            READY   STATUS             RESTARTS       AGE
mongo-client-69596b5848-j5nnz   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   6 (4m3s ago)   10m
mongo-client-746579c458-b9mrw   0/1     Completed          2 (29s ago)    35s
mongodb-6fbcfb9bbd-zjc4h        1/1     Running            0              10m

PS F:\9.1P\folder> kubectl logs mongo-client-746579c458-b9mrw 
Connecting to MongoDB at mongodb://undefined:myPassword@mongo:27017/myDatabase
Failed to connect to MongoDB MongoServerError: Authentication failed.
    at Connection.onMessage (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:231:30)
    at MessageStream.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:61:60)
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at processIncomingData (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:125:16)
    at MessageStream._write (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:33:9)
    at writeOrBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:358:12)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (internal/streams/writable.js:303:10)
    at Socket.ondata (internal/streams/readable.js:731:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:293:12) {
  ok: 0,
  code: 18,
  codeName: 'AuthenticationFailed',
  connectionGeneration: 0,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(2) { 'HandshakeError', 'ResetPool' }
}
Connection to MongoDB closed

This is the error. Please let me know if any mistake is made and thank you for your help a lot.

As your username resolves to undefined you may did a typo in some variable name.

Maybe this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470
